# CSS overlaping element doesn't exactly match element under

Tags: html, css, animation

Heyy!

I'm doing a loading animation, where there is a background element having gray background, and a foreground element, that is blue, and it is moving around as the animation goes, making it longer, and shorter periodically, to make the animation more interesting.

To create the circles, i set `border-radius: 50%;`.

For the blue circle I used `clip` to halfen the element, and another overlaping gray half-circle of the same kind "following" the blue half-circle, thus making the impression of the blue circle is getting longer/shorter depending on how far away the grey half-circle is to the blue one.

My problem is that even tho every aspect of the blue and the gray half circle are identical, apart from (obviously) the `background-color` and the `transform: rotate()`, the grey element doesn't exactly overlap the blue circle, but there are trails of blue parts seen on the side of the grey element.

See picture for more details:

[image]

Okay, so the HTML looks like this for one "spinner" (let's call it that):

```
<div class="loadingBackground"></div>
<div class="loadingForeground spinAnimation"></div>
<div class="loadingCover spinAnimation"></div>
```

the `spinAnimation` class defines the name of the animation, and the duration, not too interesting for this. the Keyframe is just a rotation for 0° to 360°.

The rest of the classes:

```
.loadingCover {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 4px #d1d1d1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px, 15px, 30px, 0px);
    margin-top: -30px;

    -webkit-animation-delay: 400ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: 400ms;
    -ms-animation-delay: 400ms;
    animation-delay: 400ms;
}

.loadingBackground {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 4px #d1d1d1;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.loadingForeground {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 4px #00aeef;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px, 15px, 30px, 0px);
    margin-top: -30px;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

Comment: Do you looking for a css loader ?

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: The _trails of blue parts_ is caused by the anti-aliasing effect computer does to make the curve look smooth. To be able to provide a solution we need a working code snippet reproducing the issue, as we can't debug your image

Comment: https://codepen.io/freer4/pen/ayXYZQ

Comment: I can't do that right now, will be able on next Monday. However, I wrote every attribute I used to generate this, maybe apart from the `box-sizing: border-box` one. Ohh, and I used `border-color` instead of `background-color`, will edit if I still can